# How do I verify duplication of files in a new RAID 1 Group?

Tags: hard-drive, files, raid

I have created a RAID 1 group across two drives on my system.  The drives formerly operated independently so I had to create the pool with only one drive, move the data to it, then initialize the source drive and add it to the pool.  The hard drive LED was solid for 10-15 minutes and then stopped.  It took literally hours, as in all night long, to rsync the 12TB of data from one drive to the other the first time, so it doesn't seem like the duplication of data to the newly added drive should have completed that fast.

Is there a way for me to verify the contents of the individual drives, to ensure that the data has indeed been copied?  `iotop` is also showing no activity on my drives.

[image]

Note: I am aware this question was asked before, but it was asked in 2016 and the only response was a comment that said "start a bounty", so I'm asking here again for my own benefit, and to get fresh perspective from people who might not have seen the question the first time it was asked 3 years ago.

Comment: I see when doing cat /proc/mdstat that even though the second drive is part of the pool, it not actually being used as of yet.  I will have to do some reading up on how to force it to actually use the drive.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I've figured out what's going on here.  I can't say how to look at the individual files on each system, but after running cat /proc/mdstat I noticed that although the drive says it's not functioning properly, there's a progress meter labeled "Recovery" that has moved up with time.  I'm new to RAID on Linux and so at first, I didn't understand what I was looking at.  However, after re-running the command a few times and noticing the progress bar moving, and verifying the the HDD LED on the server is blinking, it has become apparent that the duplication is still in progress, and since it isn't finished yet, that is probably the reason the drive is showing up as not functioning properly.

[image]